# Make columns in Kendo Grid resizable when data is aggregated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, resize, kendo-grid, aggregate

I have a kendo grid in an MVC web app that aggregates data.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Custodias.Models.TeamSummaryModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.EmpType).Width(70).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirmName).Width(150).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserName).Width(120).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectNbr).Width(70).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectFullName).Width(150).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SumDuration).ClientTemplate("#=SumDuration==null? '': kendo.toString(SumDuration, 'n') #").Width(120).Filterable(false).ClientGroupFooterTemplate("Total: #=kendo.toString(sum, 'n') #").ClientFooterTemplate("Total: #=kendo.toString(sum, 'n') #");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("FirmName").Ascending())
         .Aggregates(aggregates =>
         {
             aggregates.Add(p => p.SumDuration).Sum();
         })
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");
        })
        .Group(groups => groups.AddDescending(p => p.EmpType))
        .Read(read => read.Action("BindTeamSummaryModel", "TeamSummary").Data("TeamSummaryFilterModel"))
    )
)
```

I want the columns to be resizeable, and I know that can be achieved by just tacking on:

```
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
```

But it doesn't work. The columns aren't resizable. I've tried this on a few other Kendo Grids that DON'T aggregate data and they work just fine. Therefore, I have to assume aggregating the data adds a level of complexity to the equation.

Anyone know what the trick is?

Comment: Well you definitely need to have `.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))` set in the grid. Is the resize handle icon showing when you hover on the border between the columns? Might try removing the `.Width` property from a column and see if that changes anything.

Comment: No, the resize handle icon is NOT showing. All the others grids I've applied `.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))` to are using the `.Width` property and can resize just fine.

Comment: UPDATE (07/06/2021): If I remove the .Group() property from the grid, the columns become resizeable, but the headers no longer line up with the columns and the sub-totals go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Progress's Support Team I found that there was Javascript and CSS hiding certain sections of the grid, such as the grouping row, and then adjusting the rest of the grid to compensate. This was what caused my issue.